# checkbox: change state of checkbox by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am using checkbox in my php file.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="response" name="response" value="email">Email
</label>
```

I am retrieving the data from database by using Ajax. I want to change the state of checkbox as per the database data. In database data are **0** or **1**.

I can see data is coming properly from database but i don't know how can i use that to change state of checkbox.

```
$("#autofill").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "autofill.php",
        cache: false,
        // dataType: 'json',
        data: 'action1=' + data1,
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#response').val(data.response);
        }
    })
});
```

As per my understanding `$('#response').val(data.response);` will not work. But not sure what do i need to put there.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `prop()` method like following in your `success` callback.

```
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#response').prop('checked', data.response == 1); //add this line
}
```

It will check the checkbox if `data.response` is `1`, otherwise uncheck.

Answer (score 3):

On your success function set the checkbox to checked

```
if(data.response)
  $('#response').attr('checked','checked');
```

Though using the prop method is better/newer really

```
    // new property method
 if(data.response)
    $('#response').prop('checked', true);
```

Will check if data.response holds a value that evaluates to true

Comment: using .attr() for this is deprecated and should not be used. .prop() is the correct solution. "As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method." - http://api.jquery.com/attr/